# Should this be a constexpr or not?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

Consider this code snippet ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8PGd3o)):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

struct Option
{
    std::string_view name;

    constexpr Option( std::string_view const n ) noexcept : name{n} {}
};

template< std::size_t N >
class TransformedOption : public Option
{
public:
    constexpr TransformedOption( std::string_view const nameStr ) :
        Option{ { nameStorage_, N - 1 } }
    {
        for ( auto i = 0U; i < N; ++i )
        {
            if ( nameStr[ i ] == '_' ) { nameStorage_[ i ] = '-'; }
            else                       { nameStorage_[ i ] = nameStr[ i ]; }
        }
    }
    private:
        char nameStorage_[ N ] = {};
};

template< std::size_t N >
constexpr TransformedOption< N > make( char const (&nameStr)[ N ] ) noexcept
{
    return TransformedOption< N  >{ nameStr };
}

int main()
{
    /*constexpr*/ auto t = make( "abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_peqst" );
    std::printf( "%s\n", t.name.data() );
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I want to perform compile-time string transformation by replacing each `_` with `-` and making sure that the final binary contains only the transformed string (not the original).

I've tried Clang 10.0.1, GCC 10.2 and MSVC 19.24 (see above godbolt link). The weird stuff the following:

- if `constexpr` is commented-out in `main`, then MSVC generates incorrect code (i.e. runtime transformation of string), but both GCC and clang generate correct code (i.e. transformed string constant is embedded into the assembly)
- if `constexpr` is not commented-out in `main`, then MSVC generates correct code (i.e. transformed string constant is embedded into the assembly), but both GCC and clang fail to compile the code, stating that `t` is not initialized by constant expression (see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/o1zch7)). The weirdest thing is the GCC error message, which outputs the **transformed** string in its error and states that it's not a constant expression.

Well, which compiler is right, according to the C++ standard? To whom should I report a bug? To GCC and Clang folks or to Microsoft?

Comment: "*MSVC generates incorrect code (i.e. runtime transformation of string)*" That is correct code. Compilers are not *required* to do anything at compile-time unless it is necessary. `constexpr` on functions is an option except when called within a context that *requires* a constant expression.

Comment: It's interesting that, once you get rid of the `Option` base class (and just generate the `string_view` as needed via a function call), [the code works just fine on all compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/c75bzc). So there may be something going on in the base class that's confusing the compilers.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I know that this is correct code. It's incorrect for my cause, though (i.e. it's not what I wanted to achieve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `constexpr` declaration works in all compilers when `t` is also declared static.

```
constexpr static auto t = make( "abcd_efgh_ijkl_mnop_peqst" );
```

The reason is the `string_view`. It's a reference type that refers into the object being initialized. So one way or another, you are initializing a `contexpr` pointer. Now, a `constexpr` pointer (that is not initialized to a null pointer) may only be initialized with the address of an object with static storage duration.

> **[expr.const]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11) A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant
> expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
> constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant
> expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - if the value is an object of class type, each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted
>   result of a constant expression,
> - **if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such
>   an object ([expr.add]), the address of a non-immediate function, or a
>   null pointer value**,
> - if the value is of pointer-to-member-function type, it does not designate an immediate function, and
> - if the value is an object of class or array type, each subobject satisfies these constraints for the value.
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an
> object with static storage duration that either is not a temporary
> object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above
> constraints, or if it is a non-immediate function.

When you declare the object to be of automatic storage duration, the pointer in the `string_view` is not initialized with the address of a static object. Hence GCC and Clang rightfully complain.

The self reference is what makes this interesting and tricky.

Comment: The specific rule is: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11

Comment: Thank you! So, I guess, this is a bug in MSVC - it should have also reported an error? Also, it would be nice if both GCC and clang printed a more helpful error message (e.g. citing the rule you cited here).

Comment: @DoDo - Yes, MSVC is definitely wrong to accept the automatic `constexpr` variable. As far as the QoI of Clang and GCC, there may be options that make them print where in the constant evaluation they encountered a problem. I don't recall them off the top of my head, however.

Comment: @DoDo Clang actually tells you the problem ("pointer to subobject of 't' is not a constant expression"), although it'd be great if it gave you the callstack as well. Submitted [96557](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96557) to gcc.